# No server-side prepared statements using MySQL Connector/J

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, mysql-connector

From what I understand, MySQL 5.1 supports server-side prepared statements. Therefore the following code should prepare the statement once, and execute it 10 times:

```
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_id=?");
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        stmt.setString(1, "FOO"+i);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery();
        res.close();
    }
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
```

What I see instead in the mysqld log is the query being executed directly:

```
    SELECT @@session.tx_isolation
    SELECT USER()
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_id='FOO0'
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_id='FOO1'
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_id='FOO2'
            ...
```

I see the query sent in the full each time in the protocol logs too (using tcpdump).

Using Connector/J 5.1.12 and MySQL 5.1.44. No funny JDBC options in the JDBC URL. Going straight to the driver for this test, no pool.

Why aren't the statements being prepared?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Connector/J driver handles prepared statements locally unless you turn on real server side statements using the connection parameter `useServerPrepStmts=true`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: I'm not sure if this has been fixed since then (reading changelogs isn't my idea of a good time), but there were a bunch of problems with server-side prepared statements and so they were disabled by default in Connector/J (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/en/news-5-0-5.html).